# Google App Script - How to get all values of a specified row?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a bit new to Google App script, but I recognize it's essentially javascript with google libraries and the like.

As for my problem, i'm trying to make a script that calls a function with the values of an entire row upon edit in a certain range. To set the range "boundary" I've currently got this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if (
    e.range.columnStart >= 3 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 9 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 13 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 101
  )
  {
    Logger.log("Edit in range");
    var editRow = (e.range.rowStart, e.range.rowEnd)
    Logger.log("Edit Row: " + editRow);
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Log("Edit outside of Range");
  }
}
```

This currently works and logs if the edit is in the specified range, and also logs which row the edit has been made in. What I need to figure out, is how to get the values of the entire row of that edited cell so I can pass it to a function.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: E.range.getvalue or e.range.getvalues, please try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the values for the edited range.

You have already used 
[Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
 to identify and evaluate the limits of the edited range. 
You can use that same information to:

- `getSheet()`
- `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, and then
- `getValues()` from the range

---

```
function onEdit(e){



  if (
    e.range.columnStart >= 3 &&
    e.range.columnEnd <= 9 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 13 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 101
  )
  {
    Logger.log("Edit in range");
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    var editRowRange = sheet.getrange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1);
    var editRow = editRowRange.getvalues();
    Logger.log("Edit Row: " + editRow);
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Log("Edit outside of Range");
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using `Logger.log()` to determine where it was getting hung up, but it never shows more than "Edit in range". [This](https://pastebin.com/7rBNpKtQ) is what i'm working with currently. I was going to try to loop through the array set by `getValues()` but I can't even get that far.

Comment: You never see more than "Edit in range" because the lines after that are using "e" as the parameter, whereas you use "edit" in your `IF` statement. So, "var sheet" s.be `edit.range.getSheet()` and "var editRowRange" s.be  `sheet.getRange(edit.range.rowStart,edit.range.columnStart,edit.range.rowEnd-edit.range.rowStart+1,edit.range.columnEnd-edit.range.columnStart+1);`". Note capital R in `getRange()` and capital V in `getValues()`.